# Config xampp to import csv's to prestashop

Tags: csv, xampp, prestashop

I have a copy of my e-shop in my local server (XAMPP). The computer it's an i7 3820 16gb ram with xampp installed in SSD.

I change this values in php.ini file:

**memory_limit** -1

**max_input_time** 9999999999

**max_execution_time** 9999999999

**max_file_uploads** 1024

**post_max_size** 2048M

**upload_max_filesize** 120M

I'm trying to import by the csv importations tool included in Prestashop (v1.6) a file with more or less 9000 rows. The file is like this:

**ID**: 1

**Attribute**: AAA:select:1%BBB:select:2%CCC:select:3%DDD:select:4%EEE:select:5%FFF:select:6

**Value**: UUU:1%VVV:2%WWW:3%XXX:4%YYY:5%ZZZ:6

**Price impact**: 999

(I used "%" instead of "," to split rows because otherwise I have problems when the strings have "," in text)

Well. I am not able to import more than 1000 rows by file. And still takes about 60-90 minutes by file. If I try with larger files the browser returns me a timeout error.

Therefore, the question is, do you know some trick to optimize this process? another option? more parameters to change in php.ini? I appreciate any advice to help me improve the process.

Comment: I think your only options will be to split the rows into multiple files..

Comment: Why don't you import SQL instead?